# Changing input value via javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to change input value via javascript.
Everything works fine and the input value was changed successfully in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/dbv0vuhz/6/

```
(function () {
    function form_init() {

        var elements,
        len,
        i;

        elements = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
        len = elements.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].value = 'new value';
            console.log(elements);
            console.log(elements[i].value);
        }

        var dynamic_control = '<input type="text" class="input-dynamic" value="dynamic value" />';

        elements = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        len = elements.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //elements[i].innerHTML += dynamic_control;
        }

    };

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', form_init, false);
    }

    setTimeout(function () { // set 1 second timeout
        form_init();
    }, 1000);
})();
```

But when I am trying to add another input to the form via javascript the previous code does not work and the input value was not changed - http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/dbv0vuhz/5/

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are violating the html structure. You add the dynamic input markup inside the input markup for the first input, which does not make sense at all. You have to add it to the enclosing form or, better, _append_ it to the existing input tag. I guess what you see is an artefact of the browser trying to reconstruct a valid markup.

Comment: You must put all your code inside of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML structure of the first `input` is still `value="old value"`, the new value you set through JS, updates the DOM but in the HTML it still have "old value", so when you do this -

```
elements[i].innerHTML += dynamic_control; // concatenate with the input "old value" in html because in markup it's old value
```

the new value will not appear because in the HTML its "old value"

hope you understood what I mean, if you didn't then just right click on each fiddle input and then click inspect element from your browser, you will see in the markup saying value="old value" and showing "new value" in the first fiddle. The `.innerHTML` gets the HTML markup and then concatenates and finally append it.

**UPDATE:** The correct way of creating `input` as per your need will be -

```
/* create input element this way */
var dynamic_control = document.createElement('input');
dynamic_control.setAttribute('type', 'text');
dynamic_control.setAttribute('class', 'input-dynamic');
dynamic_control.setAttribute('value', 'dynamic value');

elements = document.querySelectorAll('form');
len = elements.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].appendChild(dynamic_control); // append the input element as a child of elements[i]
}
```

Use `appendChild()` instead of `innerHTML`.

**[Working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/dbv0vuhz/8/)**

Comment: Sorry, can't follow you there. Why should that be relevant? The OP processes all elements inside the form in the second loop. Regardless of their value. You mean the first input tag is kind of re-added because of the concatenation?

Comment: @arkascha yeah it is reprocessed in the second loop and the first one is destroyed.. you're right!

Comment: @RohitKumar Thank you for your answer. So what is the correct way of adding input into the form?

Comment: @webvitaly instead of using `innerHTML` you can use `appendChild` see my updated answer just gonna post..

Comment: @webvitaly yeah, that's great by the way have you understood the problem with `innerHTML`? it copied the markup (with value="old value") and hence the value="new value" was updated with "old value"..